# Align instances to point to the inside of a curve circle using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I have a curve which I have converted to a mesh and given a radius of 1m in geometry nodes. I have instances which I want to distribute along the curve but have them be aligned to the inside of the curve and pointing to its centre, like in the mockup below:

[image]

Can anyone help me do this? At the moment I can only get it to distribute the objects along the curve itself pointing outwards, like below (including my current geometry nodes setup):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You can set the normals direction by changing the value node. Depending of your object face normals.

Best wishes
Chris

[image]