# How to make multiple instances of a same object to track a specific point in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I'm using duplicate geometry node and instance on points node to create multiple objects from same objects and to arrange them on a curve and now I want to make them face at the origin.

Below provided is my geometry node setup
[image: Geometry nodes arrangement]

Below provided is my current output

[image]

[image]

Comment: It should answer your question : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/309598/align-instances-to-point-to-the-inside-of-a-curve-circle-using-geometry-nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

The *Curve to Points* node is conveniently providing as output the *Tangent* and *Normal* vectors to the curve at each *Point*. An *Align Euler to Vector* node is used to align one axis of the instanced object (X in the following picture) along one of those vectors (the normal in the following picture).

[image: Modified GN graph]

(NB: the *Duplicate Elements* node from the original GN graph is disconnected as it is counterproductive combined with an *Instance on Points* node.)